# Postgres add identity results in ERROR START value (0) cannot be less than MINVALUE (1)

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter

Tried to run this because I want the auto generated IDs to start at 0

```
alter table gender
alter column gender_id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

and got error:
`START value (0) cannot be less than MINVALUE (1)`

I'm not good at PostgreSQL yet so not sure how to get it to increment starting at 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Identity columns create a sequence in the backend. In your `sequence_option` of your identity column you have not provided the `MINVALUE` that's why by default it is considering the `MINVALUE` as `1`. So you have to explicitly define the `MINVALUE` like below:

```
ALTER TABLE gender
ALTER COLUMN gender_id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (MINVALUE  0 START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

Comment: I noticed I could also try to resequence with something like this.  `ALTER SEQUENCE gender_gender_id_seq RESTART WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1;` - it's not quite right yet though

Comment: do you know how to correct the ALTER also?  got the same error with ALTER.

Comment: your alter sequence statement is correct. this will do the required thing if `gender_gender_id_seq` exists

Comment: Add the minvalue in alter also. ALTER SEQUENCE gender_gender_id_seq MINVALUE 0 RESTART WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1;

Comment: doesn't look like it has one https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2011.htm